# Cells not taking desired height, when using GridLayoutManager with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso, gridlayoutmanager

I have created a `RecyclerView` (in a fragment) in which I am adding items dynamically using `GridLayoutManager`. In each of the cell of `RecyclerView` I am loading images from the server using Picasso.
Now the problem is that, when the images are loading for the first time, the `RecyclerView` cells take weird height as shown here:

[image]

But when I change tab and come to the home tab again, everything is the way I want, as shown here:

[image]

What I need is, to make cells take the desired width and height at the time they are getting added to the recycler view. To achieve this I have tried:

1. Get the width of the screen and set cells' height and width = screen size /2.
2. Take the width of `RecyclerView` and make cells' width and height equals to half of it.
3. I am assigning dimensions to the cell in `onCreateViewHolder` method of the adapter.

But in any case, I need to change tab (load fragment again) to give the cells the desired height.

I have specified the width and height of cell in its layout file as wrap content because I want them to get set according to screen size. I don't wanna hard code any value.

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss anything?

For detailed explanation, the code is given as follows:

Cell layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/category_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="ORAL CARE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`RecyclerView` in fragment's layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCategories"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<MedicineCategoryDataModel> categoryData = new ArrayList<MedicineCategoryDataModel>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private int itemWidth;

    public CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<MedicineCategoryDataModel> data, int width) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.categoryData = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_category_item, parent, false);
//        this is the point where I was trying to set cell's width and height. 
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String categoryName = categoryData.get(position).categoryName;
        holder.textViewCategoryName.setText(categoryName);
        String iconUrl = categoryData.get(position).iconUrl;
        EPClientLayer.getInstance().getImageHandler().loadImage(context,iconUrl, holder.imageViewCategoryIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView textViewCategoryName;
        ImageView imageViewCategoryIcon;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewCategoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            imageViewCategoryIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public String getItem(int id) {
        return categoryData.get(id).categoryName;
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `height` of the `ImageView` of your cell item to `wrap_content` instead of providing the height 0dp as you are taking the `weightSum`. I would like to recommend to implement your cell items like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/category_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="ORAL CARE"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `RecyclerView` to have the height and width set to `match_parent`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCategories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```

You do not want to hard code any height, which is fine. However, I think you might consider hard-coding the optimized height of the cell item's root `RelativeLayout` to get the desired behaviour in all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

make an SquareImageView as:

```
public class SquareImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);//replace heightMeasureSpec with widthMeasureSpec in this line 
}
}
```

use above imageView in recyclerView Item to load image using Piccasa.

use recyclerView in xml as:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:spanCount="2"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item"
    app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager">
 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

let me know if this solve your problem